# KNN classification for data sets.

Tags: matlab, knn

I have a data set of 178 with 13 attributes. I have divided them to 2 groups (100 and 78) for training and testing.

I want to determine the k nearest neighbours for each labelled samples. If the label of the sample is more common than any other label for the k nearest neighbours, then count the classification as correct, otherwise, count the classification as incorrect.

This is the part I am totally lost.

Comment: In what method are you searching? It sounds like you are trying to make a nueral network or something. What is the form of the data. Most importantly [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: try http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Where exactly are you lost? Do you not understand the idea behind kNN (which lakesh's answer suggests, and stats.SE might be able to give you a much more thorough description of)? Or do you understand the basic idea but don't know how to code nearest neighbors? How to code counting up the # correct? Or....

Comment: Thanks everyone. I understand the concept of KNN. what I'm trying to do is default( euclidean) classification and then measuring the success of this classification. I have difficulty with introducing the dataset to the KNN. I mean how am I going to tell it the first element in each row is class number and the rest are attributes for each feature.

Comment: Are any of these attributes a position, like a place x, y, z or anything? How do you actually tell how close two data points are. Please provide some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to understand the concept of KNN.

This is easier to understand.

> an object is classified by a majority vote of its neighbors, with the object being assigned to the class most common amongst its k nearest neighbors (k is a positive integer, typically small).

Look at Wikipedia for KNN: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I understand the concept of KNN. what I'm trying to do is default( euclidean) classification and then measuring the success of this classification. I have difficulty with introducing the dataset to the KNN. I mean how am I going to tell it the first element in each row is class number and the rest are attributes for each feature.